# Why Command Substitiution Works And Pipeline Not

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe

I am practing `|` pipeline to pass output.

Firstly, I tried `basename` as

```
$ basename -a $(ls test_directory/*)
```

This line works as expected and showed only file's name without directory's.

But when I try to pipe the output of `ls` to `basename`

```
$ ls test_directory/* | basename -a
```

Error message is here:

```
basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

I found [Pass the output of previous command to next as an argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782) on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) on which [one of the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108797/) mentioned:

> 1. Passing input by stdin:
>
>    ```
>    ls | wc -l
>    ```
>
>    This will count the lines in the output of ls
> 2. Passing input by command line arguments:
>
>    ```
>    wc -l $(ls)
>    ```
>
>    This will count lines in the list of files printed by ls

I can't understand the difference between "the output of `ls`" and "files printed by `ls`". Aren't they same thing? I want to understand the difference.

And  I want to understand why `ls td/* | basename -a`
didn't work.

Comment: On these instances, you can use *ls | xargs basename -a*

Comment: [Do not parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Use `find test_directory -type f -exec basename {} \;`

Comment: @bacOn Thank you for you suggestion. xargs, which is the new technique for me. I 
 will utilize it!

Comment: @pLumo   These days I have written such study command line,  "fdfind $1 $2 -x mv {} {}$3" . Your comment reminds me about the existence of "\;" . I watched it before, but have forgotten. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain the difference between `ls | wc -l` and `wc -l $(ls)`.  I am going to take an example.

#### 1. `ls | wc -l`

As mentioned in the post that this command will count the lines in the output of `ls`.

For instance I have a directory `~/Desktop/Practice/python` which contains 4 python scripts. 
Now if I use the above command, I get the following output:

```
4
```

This means the `wc -l` counts the output of `ls` which returned 4 python scripts hence count became 4

#### 2. `wc -l $(ls)`

Again as suggested by the post, this command will count lines in the list of files printed by `ls`.
Since in this case you are passing `ls` as an argument to the command

Now if I use the above command in the same directory I get following output:

```
12 palindrome1.py  
11 palindrome2.py
12 palindrome3.py
6 palindrome4.py
41 total
```

This shows that `wc -l` this time counted the number of lines present in each individual python script which was returned to it by `ls`.

### Difference b/w command line argument and standard input

The actual difference lies in the source of a command. A command could take input using either "commnad line arguments" or by taking a "Standard Input". Hence it is up to the developer of the command how to take input for a particular command.

The pipe passes the standard output of one command to the second command as standard input. Hence if the second command cannot process standard input it will throw an error. However some commands take both command line arguments and standard input like "wc" but the result is different because `wc` processes standard input and command line arguments differently.

In your case it was `basename`. If you read the man page of basename :

```
NAME
       basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames

SYNOPSIS
       basename NAME [SUFFIX]
       basename OPTION... NAME...

DESCRIPTION
       Print NAME with any leading directory components removed.  If specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       -a, --multiple
              support multiple arguments and treat each as a NAME
```

It is clearly specified that `basename` takes command line arguments for it's input. Hence pipe will not work.

### How to make pipe work

As [suggested by @bac0n](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265904/why-command-substitiution-works-and-pipeline-not#comment2142360_1265904), to execute the `basename` with pipe you need to use `xargs`.

```
ls | xargs basename -a
```

This works because `xargs` takes standard input and passes to another command as "command line argument".

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your support.  I have understood commands works differently with pipline or command line arguments. Anyway, although you are saying "It is clearly specified that basename takes command line arguments for it's input. Hence pipe will not work",  is it this line?: "Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too."  Does the word "arguments" here includes command line arguments?

Comment: Yes, that line means command line arguments. I would also like to mention that when you develop a program or script whatever input you take from terminal succeeding the command name is called command line argument, that include "-a" or "-s" as well. But they are also called command options or command switches as they are used to make a command work differently and the values passed to these options are called arguments/parameters. So there can be confusion sometime but I hope you get the idea of what I am saying.

Comment: I will try not to misunderstand advices with caring about what meaning the word used there has, then when I explain something, I will choose what words I shoud use. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I can demonstrate it:

[image]

Some commands are built to accept `stdin`. Take `cat` as an example. You can pipe the output of previews command to `cat`:

```
$ echo hi | cat
```

Some commands only get arguments as input, for example `echo`. If you run:

```
$ ls | echo
```

It would pipe the output of `ls` to `echo`. But `echo` won't receive it. To use `echo` you have to give it some arguments:

```
$ echo "I'm an argument"
```

If you need to use a command's output as an argument to some other command (For example in a case when it only accepts arguments and not `stdin`), you have different choices. One is to use command substitution:

```
$ echo $(ls)
```

In this case `ls` would run then the output of `ls` would be passed as arguments to the `echo`.

Same for `basename`. You have to pass arguments.

Also there are commands which are able to take argument and `stdin` at the same time. For example `cat`. If you pipe something to `cat` it would print it out. However for an argument it except you to pass a `filename` to prints its contents out.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very newbie friendly thanks to the figure. The beginner like me may be confused due to the invalidity of one of ways which seems similar. It helps me a lot to know commands can not use some way without built-in functions.